# Из нескольких div'ов вычислить одинаковые, и вложить один в другой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько дивов, одинакового класса, но он мне не известен, и формируется на лету.
Необходимо найти одинаковые блоки и вложить один в другой. Порядок не имеет значения.
Отбор предлагается сделать по некоторым переменным, которые мне дает функция.
Например:

```
<div class='cib-tile-elem'>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="12"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="12"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="14"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="12"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="38"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="32"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="12"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="14"><div class ="field"></div>
</div>
 //конечная разметка должна выглядеть примерно так:
<div class='cib-tile-elem'>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="12"><div class ="field"><div class ="field"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="14"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="12"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="38"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="32"><div class ="field"></div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="14"><div class ="field"></div>
</div>
```

Нужен скрипт, который пробежится по сформированной странице, найдет одинаковые див и вложит их друг в друга.

Вот мой код:

```js
 var classes = $(".cib-tile-elem")
 var dataid = $(this['data-id']).map(function(elem) {});
 var countSes = elem.length;
 console.log("dataid:", elem, countSes)
 var cache;
 for (var i = 0; i < countSes; ++i) {
   cache = elem[i];
   if (cache == elem[i]) {
     console.log(`найдено совпадение: ` + cache);
   }
 }
```

Я не могу понять, как пробежаться по массиву div'ов (`elem`), и выбрать те, в которых `data-id` одинаков. С jquery знаком не больше недели, а решение необходимо. `data-id` мне, по сути, не известен, он формируется функцией и зависит от того, что она присвоит.

Comment: Хорошо, а в чём вопрос? Если вы сами пишете скрипт и у вас какие-то затруднения, то выкладывайте код и описание ошибки. Если ожидаете, что за вас целиком напишут, то рекомендую обратиться на фриланс-биржу.

Comment: Пишу сам. Нужно только подтолкнуть где выход из трёх сосен! ясно понимаю что в упор не вижу. Но мне от этого не виднее. Скрипт(попытку, выложил.

Comment: А, вот так гораздо лучше уже.

Comment: Для кода на html/css/js можно использовать встроенный редактор. А ещё пожалуйста форматируйте код перед вставкой в вопрос, чтобы его было легко читать. (Да и вообще, форматируйте код). :)

Comment: какая разметка в результате должна получиться для примера из вопроса?

Comment: @Grundy  `<div class="cib-label-field" data-id ="12">12 12 12</div>`                   12 - это дивы, вложенные в  `<div class="cib-label-field">`,                               но самый последний вопрос, основное что мне не ясно - как выбрать только необходимые `<div>`

Comment: то есть убрать другие дивы с `data-id ="12"` а внутри текст со всех элементов, так?

Comment: добавьте пример конечной разметки в вопрос

Comment: выбрать - никак, только выбрав все и в цикле пробегаться

Comment: @Grundy добавил разметку в вопрос. То есть пробегаясь и при совпадении переносить содержимое? Так или иначе я не могу пробежаться, цикл не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения:

1. узнать список уникальных data-id
2. пробежаться по ним выбирая всех детей элементов с таким data-id
3. добавить их первому
4. опционально - удалить пустые элементы

Пример:

```js
var container = $(".cib-tile-elem");
Object.keys($(".cib-label-field").map(function() { // берем все data-id
    return $(this).data('id');
  }).toArray().reduce(function(acc, cur) { // сохраняем уникальные
    if (!acc[cur]) acc[cur] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {}))
  .forEach(function(el) { // бежим по уникальным data-id
    $('[data-id=' + el + ']') // выбирам все элементы с таким data-id
      .children() // берем у них детей
      .appendTo($('[data-id=' + el + ']:eq(0)')); //добавляем первому элементу
  });
// удаляем если надо пустые, если не надо строчку можно убрать/закомментировать
$(".cib-label-field:not(:has(div))").remove();
```

```css
.cib-label-field {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.field {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cib-tile-elem'>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="12">
    <div class="field">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="12">
    <div class="field">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="14">
    <div class="field">14</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="12">
    <div class="field">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="38">
    <div class="field">38</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="32">
    <div class="field">32</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="12">
    <div class="field">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cib-label-field" data-id="14">
    <div class="field">14</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересный вариант, подошёл мне больше, чем другие!

Answer (score 0):

По обращению к data-аттрибутам, советую почитать вот эту вот короткую статью
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes, а так же вот эту https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Есть еще функция самого jQuery (тоже `getAttribute`, кажется, называлась, о не помню уже)

Во-вторых,`cache = elem[i]; if (cache == elem[i])` -  это что-то вроде `a=3; if(a==3)` - тут можно даже и не сравнивать, если вы присвоили значение =D

Готового решения вам писать не буду, т.к. вы только учитесь и до некоторых решений луче додумываться самому, но одно из возможных решений вам подскажу:

перед циклом создайте пустой объект (допустим,  `cache = {};` ). В данном случае, его можно использовать в качестве ассоциативного массива

Кстати, касательно конструкции цикла вы малость перемудрили, мне кажется - почитайте про выбор по селекторам, дочерие элементы и цикл each

В цикле, допустим, вы уже получили data-id как-то так `dataId = elem[i].dataset.id;` (к стати, в идеале, элементы лучше сравнивать не по одному только data-id ) 
Проверяете, есть ли уже данный данный объект в cache (`if(cache[dataId])`) - если нет, добавляете `cache[dataId] = elem[i];`, если есть - добавляете в него дочерний ( функции `append` или `appendChild` - в зависимости, каким способом будете делать ). Если нужно, чтобы они вкладывались друг в друга матрешкой (а не напихались все data-id = 12 в один data-id=12), то, во втором случае, после действий с `append`, присваимваете `cache[dataId]=elem[i];`

Comment: `$(function() {
    var classes = $(".cib-tile-elem");
    classes.each(function(indx, el) {
        var dataid = $("[data-id]", el),
            obj = {};
        dataid.each(function(indx, elem) {
            var id = $(elem).data("id");
            elem = $(elem);
            obj[id] ? (obj[id].append(elem.html()), elem.remove()) : obj[id] = elem
        })
    })
});
`